# How to effectively group by two fields in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a 160GB database in BigQuery that represents events sent from apps in the last month. Each row has (among other) date field, userId field and event field.

What I need to do is to find how many unique users have used the app on certain day. For example, if user X used app three times on 2017/09/15, count him only once for that day, but if he used the app on both 2017/09/15, 2017/09/16 and 2017/09/17, count him in each of those days (only once).

What I have tried to do is group users by userId and by date and then separately count number of userIds for each date, for example:

```
SELECT
  userId,
  DATE(date) AS date_conv
FROM
  [TABLE]
WHERE
  userId IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  date_conv,
  userId
ORDER BY
  userId
```

However, this query returns "Resources exceeded", even with increased billing tier, so it would be great if there would be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to count the number of unique users, then use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS date_conv, COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as numusers
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date);
```

You are probably getting the resources exceeded because of the `ORDER BY`.

EDIT:

I haven't tried `COUNT(DISTINCT)` on a really large volume of data on BigQuery.  In some databases, nested aggregations optimizes much better:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS date_conv, COUNT(*) as numusers
FROM (SELECT DATE(date) AS date_conv, userId
      FROM [TABLE]
      GROUP BY DATE(date), userId
     ) du
GROUP BY DATE(date)
ORDER BY DATE(date);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fast and actually uses a small amount of resources.

Comment: @leonz . . . That is good to know.  I added an alternative that works better in Postgres and some other databases.